# Is "die Treuhand" used the same as "das Vertrauen"?

Tags: word-usage

I know that both mean "the trust" but I have never heard yet "treuhand" in a conversation or in books

Comment: If you have difficulties finding the appropriate German term for an English expression consider to consult another dictionary. Look at the [entry e.g. in dict.cc](https://www.dict.cc/?s=trust): using *Treuhand* as a translation for *trust* is reserved for its use as a technical law term - so it is of little surprise you don't hear it in everyday conversations.

Answer (score 8):

While "Vertrauen" means "trust" in the sense of "I put my trust in you",
"Treuhand" is a rather specific term for certain judicial and/or financial constructs. You might want to look it up in Wikipedia:

[Treuhand](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treuhand)
[Trust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trust_company)

After the German reunification, an agency named "Treuhandanstalt", often abbreviated as "Treuhand", was set up to manage the state property of the former German Democratic Republic. If someone talks about "die Treuhand" without further explanations, they most probably refer to the

[Treuhandanstalt](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treuhandanstalt)

Comment: And it is a politically loaded topic. Many germans, from both former parts, think the Treuhandanstalt did a wasteful, disrespectful, and/or corrupt job. So using that word for anything has a big risk of drawing you into an political discussion.

Comment: Even if it is a judicial construct its function and meaning is derived from "trauen". Maybe you can refine your answer a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Vertrauen means "trust" in the sense of the *feeling* thereof.

"Treuhand" refers to a financial arrangement involving an intermediary, such as a bank, as a "trustee." The arrangement itself, is a "trust."